# How can I get information about errors in laravel 6.0?

Tags: php, laravel

When I used Laravel 5.8 I could get information about errors like this :

```
@if(count($errors > 0))
     <ul class="error-list" >
         @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
           <li class="error-list-element">{{$error}}</li>
         @endforeach
    </ul>  
@endif
```

It worked completly fine.
Since Laravel 6.0 was released the code above results in error :

> Object of class Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag could not be converted to int

So how can I get information about errors in Laravel 6.0?

Comment: change `@if(count($errors > 0))` to `@if(count($errors) > 0)`

Comment: Science damn it. Stupid mistake. This topic is useless :/

Answer (score 2):

Here is code :

```
 @if ($errors->any())
      <div class="alert alert-danger">
          <ul>
              @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                  <li>{{ $error }}</li>
              @endforeach
          </ul>
      </div>
  @endif
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```